# Batch: The goto statement isn't working properly

Tags: batch-file

I have three different labels, but it doesn't matter with one I choose: It will always got to the first label (= cmd is also opening if i am writing "google")! What's the error and why is it happening?

```
@echo off
:start
set /p input = What do you want to open?
if "%input%" == "cmd" goto cmd
if "%input%" == "notepad" goto notepad
if "%input%" == "google" goto google

:cmd
start
goto start

:notepad
start notepad
goto start

:google
start https://www.google.at/
goto start
```

Answer (score 4):

Your first problem is in this line

```
set /p input = What do you want to open?
```

This line creates a variable called `"input "` with a space after it, and which is different than the `"input"` variable you're testing.  Unlike every other programming language, you can't add spaces to beautify your code.  Change the line to

```
set /p "input=What do you want to open? "
```

Your second problem is that after all three `if` statements fail (because of testing the wrong variable), CMD simply executes the next line it sees, which is the `:cmd` label.  To avoid this, you need to add a default label after your three if statements, for when the variable doesn't match.

```
if "%input%" == "cmd" goto cmd
if "%input%" == "notepad" goto notepad
if "%input%" == "google" goto google
goto default

:cmd
start
goto start
```

If you just want the script to end there and don't want to create a `:default` block, you can change it to `goto :eof`, which is a special label for the end of the script.  Or even better, use `exit /B 1` which terminates the script immediately with an error code of 1 (which another script can check using `%errorlevel%`)

Answer (score -1):

Your set /p isn't working as you think it should. input ends up empty and it falls through all of your if statements and right into the :cmd block.